# JMS Testing - JMSTemplate send not executed

Tags: unit-testing, junit, jms, mockito, spring-jms

I have code piece sending jms messages via Spring JMSTemplate. For testing the the method i use Mockito.

My code looks like following.... publishDialogueServiceMessage()->

```
 brokerUrl = jmsQueueProperties.getProperty(MessageRouterConstants.JMS_QUEUE_URL);  
        LOG.info("The broker url is : {}", brokerUrl);  
        jmsTemplate.send(jmsQueueProperties.getProperty(MessageRouterConstants.QUEUE), new MessageCreator() {

            @Override
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {             
                ObjectMessage obj = session.createObjectMessage(serviceResponse);
                messageSent = true;
                return obj;
            }
        });
```

In above code to i set boolean variable true, to check that if the message is sent

My Test looks following,

```
@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        connectionFactory = Mockito.spy(new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                "vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false"));
        conn = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        conn.start();       
    } 

@After
public void cleanUp() throws Exception{
    conn.stop();
}
```

```
@Test
    public void testPublishDialogueServiceMessage()
    {
        ServiceResponse response = Mockito.mock(
                ServiceResponse.class, Mockito.withSettings()
                        .serializable());
        JmsTemplate mockTemplate = Mockito.mock(JmsTemplate.class);
        java.util.Properties p = Mockito.mock(java.util.Properties.class);      
        Mockito.when(p.getProperty(MessageRouterConstants.QUEUE))
                .thenReturn("outbound.request.queue");
        mockTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        mockTemplate.setDeliveryPersistent(true);
        mockTemplate.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(2);
        mockTemplate.setSessionTransacted(true);

        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(publisher, "jmsQueueProperties", p);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(publisher, "jmsTemplate", mockTemplate);

        // test
        publisher.publishDialogueServiceMessage(response);
        ArgumentCaptor<MessageCreator> msgCreator = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MessageCreator.class);
        Mockito.verify(p, Mockito.times(2))
                .getProperty(Mockito.anyString());
        Mockito.verify(mockTemplate, Mockito.times(1)).send(
                Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(MessageCreator.class));

        //MessageCreator msgCrt = Mockito.spy(msgCreator.getValue());
        //Assert.notNull(msgCrt);

        Assert.isTrue(publisher.isMessageSent());
    }
```

In test i facing an interesting problem as *publisher.isMessageSent()* always returns me FALSE indicating that send message seems not executed(?). but *Mockito.verify(mockTemplate, Mockito.times(1)).send(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(MessageCreator.class));* goes fine.

I am wondering what is the cause that my messageSent variable not setting. Can anyone shed some light what I might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple, you have a mock for the `jmsTemplate` (your `mockTemplate`). When a method is invoked on a mock it doesn't do anything other than record the call to the mock. So the mock doesn't know that it should attempt to invoke the `msgCreator`.

Looking at your test I see some obvious issues that suggest a lack of knowledge of Mockito. Why are you setting all of those fields on `mockTemplate`? It is a mock, it will not use those fields anyway. This also suggests that you don't need the code in your `@Before` and `@After`.

If you REALLY want your test to send a message via JMS (and thereby invoke the message createor) you should use a `spy` on `JmsTemplate` instead of a mock. However, I would highly discourage this as your test will be dependent on an external system and you would in effect be testing `JsmTemplate`. The fact that your mock gets invoked properly is sufficient. The only additional thing I think you need to do is to invoke the message creator being passed to the mock to verify that it creates the message correctly.