# JMS Template testing : Execution failed/not captured for JmsTemplate.convertAndSend() in Test

Tags: java, testing, mockito, spring-jms

Hi am trying to write test for my Publisher class that publish the message to IBM queue using JMSTemplate and my test is as below. The test fails to execute the mock jmsTemplate method convertAndSend(). Not sure what I am doing wrong, but I couldn't find any support for testing the publisher as it is readily available in Spring Framework for other message brokers like rabbitMQ with Message Collectors.

Here is my code for the test:

'''

```
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
public class EventPublisherTest {

    EventPublisher eventPublisher;

    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    MessageCreator messageCreator;

    Session mockSession;


    @Before
    public void setup() {
        eventPublisher = Mockito.mock(EventPublisher.class);
        jmsTemplate = Mockito.mock(JmsTemplate.class);
        messageCreator = Mockito.mock(MessageCreator.class);
        mockSession = Mockito.mock(Session.class);
    }


    @Test
    public void testPublishEvent_PublishingMessage_Success() throws JMSException {
        Mockito.when(mockSession.createTextMessage(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(Mockito.any());

        Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Message>() {
            @Override
            public Message answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                final Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                final MessageCreator arg = (MessageCreator)args[0];
                return arg.createMessage(mockSession);
            }
        }).when(jmsTemplate).convertAndSend(Mockito.anyString());

        eventPublisher.publishEvent(MessageBuilder.withPayload("mockMessage").build());

        Mockito.verify(jmsTemplate, Mockito.times(1))
                .convertAndSend(Mockito.anyString());
    }
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just this `eventPublisher = Mockito.mock(EventPublisher.class);` and then there is no any stubs for that `publishEvent()` method call to make possible connection with that `jmsTemplate`.

There are no too much mocking tests with `JmsTemplate` because in most cases we do testing against embedded JMS broker like ActiveMQ.

Also I see that your `Answer` is not relevant to what you stub:

```
.when(jmsTemplate).convertAndSend(Mockito.anyString());
```

So, that `InvocationOnMock` may have only a string you send. No any `MessageCreator` is involved in the `convertAndSend()`.

I'm not sure what are your expectations from this unit test, but at the moment it is just wrong and definitely cannot work.

BTW this has nothing to do with [Spring Integration](https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration). Please, be careful next time when you choose tags for the question.

Comment: I am really sorry for adding Spring Integration, I was actually trying to add Spring Integration testing wgere components are involved.

Comment: I want to test that my publisher is able to push the message to the queue, I know in order to do this I need to use an embedded ActiveMQ but since I am using IBM MQ i was thinking to just mock the jmsTemplate that it has invoked convertAndSend() method. If you can help me figure out how to do that, that will be great, also if there is anything else I can do to make my test better I am open to suggestions.

Comment: I was trying to follow the guidelines marked in this question by Garry and other person: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476164/jms-testing-jmstemplate-send-not-executed

Comment: You can have a `JmsTemplate` mocked, but then you inject it into your "normal" `EventPublisher`. Then verify methods of that mock.